# Magento Layered navigation call to count() on undefined object

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have encountered a problem in the layered navigation block, which I believe might be a bug.

In block Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation, method _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml:

```
    // get all children
    // If Flat Data enabled then use it but only on frontend
    $flatHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat');
    if ($flatHelper->isAvailable() && $flatHelper->isBuilt(true) && !Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
        $children = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
        $childrenCount = count($children);
    } else {
        $children = $category->getChildren();
        $childrenCount = $children->count();
    }
```

I have flat category index enabled and the index is rebuilt when scheduled (every minute). Magento version is 1.14.0.1 and sometimes I get an error message:

```
Call to a member function count() on a non-object
```

Based on the if clause I am assuming that this happens when someone accesses the page while the index is being rebuilt (isAvailable).

Problem is that the code in the else block doesn't seem to even theoretically work, because $category->getChildren() returns a string. Am I missing something here? Is this a bug or do I have some wrong configuration somwhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into it further, it looks like it is a bug. The problem are race conditions:

- **Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::_construct** decides what to use, EAV or Flat resource
- **Then Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category::getStoreCategories** returns different collection based on that.
- in **Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml**, the **$category** object is either **Mage_Catalog_Model_Category** or **Varien_Data_Tree_Node** based on previous decision to use Flat or EAV.
- **Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml** checks again whether to treat the object as Flat or EAV and calls different methods based on this.

So in the case that the categories were initialized with Flat resource, and the category index process becomes locked some time after but before the last method, Magento will handle **$category** as an object of the wrong type.

My solution is to additionally check the **$category** type inside the else part.

```
} else {
        if( $category instanceof Varien_Data_Tree_Node )
        {
            $children = $category->getChildren();
        } else
        {
            $children = $category->getChildrenCategories();
        }
    }
```

What I am a bit afraid of is a problem because I am accessing category index while is is locked.

Answer (score 0):

This may be something that you can avoid by turning on cache ( all cms/catalog/category/404 pages are full pages cached in enterprise edition ) and having a scheduled cache flush after reindexing is complete. Consider increasing the interval between your reindexes.

If tweaking with the built-in settings doesn't work you can always debug:

> Create a log file and make it writable

```
touch mage-root/var/log/counts.log
chmod 755 mage-root/var/log/counts.log
```

> Replace the child calls with:

```
// get all children
// If Flat Data enabled then use it but only on frontend
$flatHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat');
Mage::log( 'Flat data enabled: '  . $flatHelper, null, 'counts.log', FALSE );
if ($flatHelper->isAvailable() && $flatHelper->isBuilt(true) && !Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
    $children = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
    Mage::log( 'Children in if: '  . $children, null, 'counts.log', FALSE );
    $childrenCount = count($children);
} else {
    $children = $category->getChildren();
    Mage::log( 'Children in else: '  . $children, null, 'counts.log', FALSE );
    $childrenCount = $children->count();
}
```

Finally you can override the vanilla class by copying it to:

> app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Navigation.php

Then adding an `if( !empty( $children ) )` above the offending statement and using this 'patch' long term.

Comment: I tried the cache thing, I have a scheduled import at 15m every hour and the cache was cleaned at the same time. I changed it to 15m later but it still happened.